# Garbage collection of objects in loop in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Q: 02 Given:

```
11. public void genNumbers() {
12.    ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
13.    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
14.       int value = i * ((int) Math.random());
15.       Integer intObj = new Integer(value);
16.       numbers.add(intObj);
17.    }
18.    System.out.println(numbers);
19. }
```

Which line of code marks the earliest point that an object referenced by intObj
becomes a candidate for garbage collection?

```
A. Line 16
B. Line 17
C. Line 18
D. Line 19
E. The object is NOT a candidate for garbage collection.
```

Answer: D

Confused why answer is D not B. Please help me understand.

Comment: Why do you think it's `B`?

Answer (score 8):

You probably think since the variables lifetime is ended at the end of the block, the object can be removed by the garbage collector. But since that object was added to the list `numbers`, it is still referenced. Therefore it's after the lifetime of `numbers` ends and the list can also be removed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

At line 17, the variable `intObj` goes out of scope, but this does only mean that there is *one less* reference to the Integer object than before. The `numbers`array still references the same object as `intObj` did, so it cannot be collected before `numbers` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

the object id garbage collected only when it is nolonger reachable by any reference.
but in our example the  new Integer(value); becomes out of rechable tointObj but it is accessed by arraylist  so we still access  the  new Integer(value); so it becomes garbage collected only when arraylist becomes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The object `intObj` is created at line 15, and a reference to it is added to `numbers` in line 16. While `intObj` goes out of scope at line 17, it is still referenced by `numbers`, which does not go out of scope until line 19.